# Unity3d: Find a point on the line which has shortest distance from the third point

Tags: unity, c#, mathematics, raycasting

[image]

So, initially, I had points `A and C`. To get `point B`, I had to shoot a raycast down from `point A` and get the `hit.point`, which is `point B` now. `Point D` is somewhere between the raycast I shot from `A` and perpendicular to `C`. How do I find the `point D`.

Comment: I answered, but it seems that you don't even need a raycast. What purpose does it have?

Comment: Nothing important! I shouldn't have mentioned it!

Comment: You could use just any second point to define the line, not nessessary the result of raycast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so your task is actually to project point onto line, defined by two points.

Code:

```
XY d = a + XY.Project (c - a, b - a);
```

`XY` is a 2-dimensional vector with these methods defined:

```
/// projection of vector v onto vector w
public static XY Project (XY v, XY w) => XY.Dot (v, w) / XY.Dot (w, w) * w;

/// dot product of vectors a and b
public static float Dot (XY a, XY b) => a.X * b.X + a.Y * b.Y;
```

Also you'll have to implement trivial `+-*/` operators.